# How do I print out the content of a register in Hex

Tags: nasm

I'm currently getting started with NASM and wanted to know, how to output the contents of a register with NASM in Hexadecimal.
I can output the content of eax with

```
section .bss
    reg_buf: resb 4
.
.
.
print_register:
    mov [reg_buf], eax
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, SYS_OUT
    mov ecx, reg_buf
    mov edx, 4
    int 80h
    ret
```

Let's say eax contains 0x44444444 then the output would be "DDDD". Apparently each pair of "44" is interpreted as 'D'. My ASCII table approves this.

But how do I get my program to output the actual register content (0x44444444)?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i was taught to do it..

```
.
.
SECTION .data
numbers: db "0123456789ABCDEF" ;; have initialized string of all the digits in base 16
.
.
.
  ;;binary to hex

mov al , byte [someBuffer+someOffset] ;; some buffer( or whatever ) with your data in
mov ebx, eax  ;; dealing with nybbles so make copy for obtaining second nybble

and al,0Fh   ;; mask out bits for first nybble
mov al, byte [numbers+eax] ;; offset into numbers is the hex equiv in numbers string
mov byte [someAddress+someOffset+2], al
;;store al into a buffer or string or whatever it's the first hex number

shr bl, 4 ;; get next nybble
mov bl, byte [numbers+ebx] ;; get the hex equiv from numbers string
mov byte [someAddress+someOffset+1], bl
;;place into position next to where al was stored, this completes the process,
;;you now have your hexadecimal equivalent output it or whatever you need with it
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your register as a text string first. The simplest to use API would likely be `itoa`, followed by your write call. You will need a string buffer allocated for this to work.

If you don't want to do it in assembly, you can make a quick C/Python/Perl/etc program to read from your program and make all output text.